# Delete libvirt qemu account from login screen

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, accounts

I uninstalled libvirt qemu but still it's showing in lock/switch accounts , How i delete from this.?

Answer (score 1):

I've just done it by doing the following procedure:

1. Click on the right top corner of the Ubuntu screen
2. Choose System Settings
3. Click User Accounts
4. Select Qemu Account
5. Confirm deleting everything

Answer (score 0):

In a command terminal, assuming the actual userid is `qemu`

1. check the `UID` value. If it is `0`, this process is not for you

   getent passwd qemu | cut -d: -f3
2. read `man deluser`, and do something like:

   sudo deluser --remove-all-files --backup qemu

I don't know of a GUI method.